# Sending correct values from a form to a report in Access 2003

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I have a form that allows the user to type down 50 different part numbers and print out the amount of labels needed to be printed for each part number. The problem I'm having is that when I send the part numbers to the label report, the amount of labels is incorrect. Here's what I have:

```
Private Sub cmdPrint_Click()
'Printing multiple labels for one record
Dim i As Integer
Dim a As Integer
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim total As Integer

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
'Delete previous label data
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM [tmpParts]"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

On Error GoTo errHandler
'Catch blank QTY
'If set to 0, label report is blank but runs
If IsNull(Me!QTY) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter the quantity for labels", _
    vbOKOnly, "Error"
    DoCmd.GoToControl "QTY"
    Exit Sub
End If

rst.Open "[tmpParts]", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, 
adLockPessimistic
'Adds duplicate records for selected item using input value
For total = 1 To Total_QTY.Value
    For i = 1 To QTY.Value
    With rst
        .AddNew
        !Item_Number = Me.Combo_1.Column(1)
        !Item_Description = Me.Item_Desc
        !Bin = Me.Bin_Loc
        .Update
    End With
    Next i
    For j = 1 To QTY_2.Value
    With rst
        .AddNew
        !Item_Number = Me.Combo2.Column(1)
        !Item_Description = Me.Item_2
        !Bin = Me.Bin_2
        .Update
    End With
    Next j

Next total
    DoCmd.OpenReport "rptTemporaryLabels", acViewPreview
    'DoCmd.PrintOut
    'DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdClose
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Exit Sub

errHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbOKOnly, "Error"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```

Right now it is incomplete as I only have 2 qty boxes just for testing purposes. I'm trying to make it so that if QTY says 3 for that part number and QTY_2 says 2 for the other part number, the label will reflect it.

Comment: Bear in mid a lot of collections are zero based, like the recordset, while your loops start from one. If this doesn't solve the problem provide more detail.

Comment: It did not. What's happening is when I send the 2 QTY text boxes along with their respective part numbers to the report they don't create the exact number requested, so for an example if I put 1 qty for 2 items and print them to the report, it doesn't come out with just 2 labels but rather 44 of them

Comment: So you need to set a breakpoint at the start of your code and inspect each of the variables as they are populated. http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s196/breakpoints.htm

Comment: Okay so I noticed the first error was that I forgot to do Me.QTY.Value, which works if it's only using the first qty box, when trying to add the second qty box it bumps it up to 44 again.

Comment: I just separated the 2 boxes into their own for statements and now they work fine, the problem being is that now I have to copy and paste it 48 more times since there are 50 lines that can be filled and sent to the report.

Comment: Post your amended code and comment where you have to to do the copy and paste